# Find command. How to process founded files to gunzip and then to grep by pattern

Tags: linux, grep, find, exec, gunzip

Example:

```
find . -name 'audit_log*.gz' -print -exec gunzip -c {} \| grep IP  \;
```

Need to add a key to this to get:
-file name.
-list IP from audit_log*.gz files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used the semi-column incorrectly. It should be at the end of the find command and before the pipe. Try this one-liner:

```
find . -type f -iname 'audit_log*.gz' -exec gunzip -c {} \; | grep IP
```

Comment: But we need to display IP in what file of audit_log.gz.

Comment: You can use loop to apply the gunzip execution to all files discovered by the find command.

`find . -type f -iname 'audit_log*.gz' | while read i; do gunzip -c "$i" | grep IP;done`

Comment: But I've have on filename, just filtered as grep
find . -type f -iname 'audit_log*gz' | while read i; do gunzip -c "$i" | grep IP|wc -l;done
95
94
97
95
96
96
96
95
97

Comment: Thanks a lot, add this; do echo$i;gunzip -c "$i"  !